# Tracing Request Process time in classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, iis-7, asp-classic

Working on performance issue with classic ASP application.

I would like to trace the request start time and the request end time, like how we do it in ASP.Net application's global.asax.cs file's BeginRequest and EndRequest or using some HTTPModule.

**Is there a way in asp application runs under IIS can implement the same?**

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a close approximation using vbScript's `Timer()` function.  This function returns the number of seconds and milliseconds since 12:00 AM.  The granularity leaves something to be desired if you are really trying to measure high-performance operations, but for everyday usage I've had some success.

You could use the function something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim startTime
Dim executionTime

startTime = Timer()
' Do some stuff here that takes a while....'
executionTime = Timer() - startTime

Response.Write "Execution time: " & executionTime
```